# Can Glue(crawlers) and athena do change management?

Tags: amazon-web-services, etl, amazon-athena, aws-glue

Glue creates Parquet Files in s3 from a JDBC source.

### Schema:

### col1 col2 timestamp

key1   val1     Today
key2   val2     Today

Parquet File created for Today. Can be queried by Athena.

Tomorrow update on source table(temp) i.e key2 value has been changed and two more rows are added.

### Schema:

### col1 col2 timestamp

key2   val3     Tomorrow
key3   val4     Tomorrow
key4   val5     Tomorrow

New Parquet File is created for tomorrow with only 3 rows(key2, Key3, Key4).

How can we use Glue/Athena to update key2 value with the timestamp in the destination table..

Desired Output:

---

### col1 col2 timestamp

key1   val1      Today
key2   val3      Tomorrow
key3   val4      Tomorrow
key4   val5      Tomorrow

Answer (score 2):

Glue only manages schema changes, no data changes

Comment: A little more detail on this answer would make it valuable.

Answer (score 0):

> Glue creates Parquet Files in s3 from a JDBC source.

Are these files being exported to different partitions ("folders") in the target S3 bucket?

Example: "s3://target-bucket/year=2018/month=4/day=1/*files-here*"

If so, create and schedule a Glue crawler to periodically crawl the target S3 bucket **after** the Glue JDBC extraction job. The crawler will update the Athena table's definition adding all new partitions and making new data queriable.

**Summary:**

Step 1)

```
GLUE JOB -- exports --> S3 BUCKET
```

Step 2)

```
GLUE CRAWLER --> crawls --> S3 BUCKET --> updates --> ATHENA TABLE'S DEFINITION
```

Please note that you shouldn't change your table's schema (i.e., column's names, types, and order) as Glue currently does not support parquet files to mutate datatypes or allow the reordering of columns. They are already working on a fix though. You could change your data's format to JSON if this is a must-have feature.